# Unix loop to read flat file and update statement

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop, while-loop, scripting

I have been working on creating a loop that will read through a flat file, and insert the values into a pre-generated emcli statement. The flat file contains the `target_name` and `target_type` of 47 targets, separated by spaces. The `emcli` command that I am trying to update for each target is:

```
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="target_name@@target_type@@Department@@dept_name"
```

I am having trouble starting the loop as I don't know how to make it read through the file and update the values into the statement. I don't have much experience scripting.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: can you post your input file and expected command after reading the while file, @EtanReisner also note that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @ritesht93 I'm not sure what you were trying to get me to see but yes, the shell is not a very good solution for reading large files (because it doesn't perform very well for that) but it is perfectly reasonable and specifically on-topic for this question also when you need to use the contents to run other commands then it is likely that the shell reading time will not dominate the run time. But yes, if you can use something like `awk` instead that is generally preferable.

Comment: @ritesht93 I can't post the input file, I dont think I am allowed to as the servers listed are private and belong to the company I work for. But, the file is basically "target_name        target_type" over and over. These target types are things such as hosts, j2ee_application, metatdata_repository, EM Console Service, oracle_oms_pbs, weblogic_j2eeserver, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Solution is based on following assumptions.*

As per your comments, the flat file will only have `target_name` `target_type` as per below.

**Flat File `a.txt` :**

```
host1 hosts
host2 j2ee_application
host3 metatdata_repository
host4 EM
host5 Console
host6 Service
host7 oracle_oms_pbs
host8 weblogic_j2eeserver
```

**Shell Script:**

The script then just need to read first and second field while iterating through each line and update `emcli` command with `target_name`  and `target_type`.

`/\` is added for `"` appearing inside the `echo` statement so that entire command / statement is printed correctly.

`grep -v ^$` ignores any blank lines.

```
cat a.txt |grep -v ^$ |
    while read target_name target_type
    do
        echo  "emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records=\"@@\" -property_records=\"${target_name}@@${target_type}@@Department@@dept_name\""
    done
```

**Result:**

```
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host1@@hosts@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host2@@j2ee_application@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host3@@metatdata_repository@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host4@@EM@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host5@@Console@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host6@@Service@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host7@@oracle_oms_pbs@@Department@@dept_name"
emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host8@@weblogic_j2eeserver@@Department@@dept_name"
```

Comment: So, I tried this... but the output is coming out as
    emcli set_target_property_value -subseparator=property_records="@@" -property_records="host1@@@@Department@@dept_name"

With a separate emcli command for the target type

Comment: Actually, this works! Thank you. I looked into the flat file and it had it listed as
host1
host
host2
j2ee_application
and skipped a line for each of them

Comment: Glad it worked, can you accept the answer and vote accordingly :-)